# Probability of getting less than N points given that you get at least K

Tags: probability, dynamic-programming, programming

The question can be described as follows. You have a die that rolls between 1 and W max points. You stop rolling when you hit K points. What is the probability you get N points or less? This is actually this leetcode question here: https://leetcode.com/problems/new-21-game/.

I am really confused by the posted solution so I thought I would ask on math.stackexchange. In the solution, people calculate the probability of getting i points where i is any number between 1 and K + W - 1. This is because you stop rolling when you hit K points.

Then, the final solution is given as the sum of the probabilities you found between K and N. This seems incorrect to me. Shouldn't it be a conditional probability? Shouldn't it be the sum of the probabilities from K to N divided by the sum of the probabilities from K and K + W - 1.

If anyone could enlighten me here, that would be appreciated.

Comment: If you stop if and only if you have accumulated $K$ points, then the sum of probabilities between $K$ and $K+W-1$ inclusive is $1$

Comment: Yes this is what i am claiming but this is not what the solution on leetcode says.

Comment: i may be missing something here. Sum of probabilities from $K$ to $N$, divided or not divided by the sum of probabilities from $K$ to $K+W-1$ are the same because the later is $1$ right?

Comment: How can we prove this though?

Comment: As long as you are sure that all possible outcomes are in $[K,K+W-1]$ then the sum of probabilities there must be $1$

Comment: For simplicity, suppose that you are the 1st to act in the actual game of blackjack, and suppose that all Aces must count as $11$, and assume that you always stop on 17 or higher, but never stop on 16 or lower.  Then, your final amount must be some number between $17$ and $27$ inclusive.  Further, these $11$ events are mutually exclusive.  Therefore, the sum of the probabilities of these $11$ events must add up to $1$.  Isn't this analogy apt for the cited game, where various final tallies are mutually exclusive and are exhaustive of all possibilities?

Comment: Yes but then the calculation given in the problem is using DP[I] where i DP[i] is defined as the probability of getting i. This is not true. This is not accurate.

Comment: We are using the fact that the sum is higher than k or more to prove that it the sum is 1. How can you go from the definition of DP[i] to the fact that the sum must be equal to 1. Does my confusion make sense?

Comment: I only glanced at the cited article.  However, the issue of whether there is a programming or analytical flaw is a separate issue.  For simplicity, let's focus on the blackjack game that I described.  For $k \in \{17, 18, \cdots, 27\}$, let $a_k$ denote the probability that the final tally is $k$ or higher, and let $b_k$ denote the probability that the final tally is exactly $k$.  If I understand correctly, you agree that $b_{17} + b_{18} + \cdots + b_{27} = 1.$

Comment: Then, I would argue that $b_{17} = a_{17} - a_{18}, b_{18} = a_{18} - a_{19}, \cdots b_{26} = a_{26} - a_{27}.$  Then, $b_{27} = a_{27}.$  If you agree with all of this, then it seems as if your **real** question is that you think that an analytical mistake has been made in the analogous game, when calculating either the analogous variables $a_k$, or the analogous variables $b_k$.  Certainly, more than possible.  However, such an analytical mistake doesn't imply that the whole approach is unsound.  ...see next comment

Comment: Instead it simply indicates that someone hasn't correctly analyzed how to calculate the pertinent variables.  Do you agree?

Comment: No no so the approach gives you the correct answer but in the approach they define DP[i] but how DP[i] is defined seems unsound.

Comment: What is DP[i] in this instance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129758/discussion-between-snickers-stickers-and-user2661923).